# Can I fix my Quick bread?

Tags: baking

I added 3/4 cup of oil instead of water to a quick bread mix. Can it be saved?

Comment: Can you please post the full recipe?

Answer (score 0):

Oil/fat would be a common ingredient in quickbread (and varying its amount will usually just change but not ruin texture), it would be advisable to still add the water though because while doughs with hardly any water will work, they tend to get very firm and crisp (pie crusts,shortbreads and cookies are made that way). If the consistency with the oil incorporated is hard to work with, add flour until workable, but remember that you might have to also add extra leavening if a significant amount of flour is added.